# How to evaluate $\int \frac{1}{\cos^2 x (e^x + 1)} \,dx$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

The indefinite integral 
 $$\int \frac{1}{\cos^2 x (e^x + 1)} dx$$
appears to be impossible to evaluate in closed form.

Could you please suggest how I should evaluate this integral in definite form? 
 $$\int_{-a}^a \frac{1}{\cos^2 x (e^x + 1)} dx$$

Comment: what did you tried, what's the context?

Comment: Mathematica is unable to evaluate this integral.

Answer (score 7):

I suppose you are integrating over an interval:
$$\int_{-a}^{a} \frac{1}{\cos^2 x (e^x + 1)} dx=\int_0^a\frac{dx}{\cos^2 x(e^x+1)}+\frac{dx}{\cos^2x(1+e^{-x})}=\int_0^a\frac{dx}{\cos^2 x}=[\tan x]_0^a=\tan a$$